# Selfadjoint Endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inner-products, linear-transformations, adjoint-operators

Question:

Let $p >1$ be an integer, let $G = \mathbb{Z}/(p)$, and let $V = \mathbb{C}^G$, which is an inner
product space over $\mathbb{C}$ with inner product defined by $\langle f, g\rangle =\sum_{n\in G}f(n)\overline{g(n)}$.
Let $\alpha$ be the endomorphism of $V$ defined by $\alpha(f): n \mapsto f(n+1) + f (n - 1)$.
Is $\alpha$ selfadjoint?

My work:

Selfadjoint: $\langle \alpha(f),g \rangle = \langle f,\alpha(g)\rangle$

Additionally, we have 
Proposition 17.2: Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $\alpha \in End(V)$ have an adjoint. If $\langle \alpha(v), v\rangle \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $v \in V$ , then $\alpha$ is selfadjoint.

Also, we take note of the fact that $G=\mathbb{Z} / (p)= \{0,1,...,p-1\}$ and thus, $n\in G \subset \mathbb{Z}$.

\begin{align*}
\langle \alpha(f), f \rangle &= \langle 
f(n+1) + f(n-1), f(n) \rangle =
\langle f(n+1),f(n) \rangle + \langle f(n-1),f(n)\rangle \\[1ex]
&= \sum_{n\in G}f(n+1)\overline{f(n)}+\sum_{n\in G}f(n-1)\overline{f(n)}
\end{align*}

And then I'm stuck. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Following your calculation, we have

$$ \overline{\left< \alpha(f), f \right>} = \sum_{n \in G} f(n) \overline{f(n+1)} + \sum_{n \in G} f(n) \overline{f(n-1)} = \sum_{m \in G} f(m-1) \overline{f(m)} + \sum_{m' \in G} f(m' + 1) \overline{f(m')} = \left< \alpha(f), f \right> $$

where we used the change of variables $m = n + 1$ and $m' = n - 1$ for the sums. This shows that $\left< \alpha(f), f \right>$ is real for all $f \in V$.

Answer (score 3):

If you set $n-1=m$, then the second summation becomes
$$
\sum_{m\in G}f(m)\overline{f(m+1)}=
\sum_{n\in G}f(n)\overline{f(n+1)}
$$
So
\begin{align}
\langle \alpha(f),f\rangle
&=\sum_{n\in G}(\alpha(f)(n),f(n))\\
&=\sum_{n\in G}(f(n+1)+f(n-1))\overline{f(n)}\\
&=\sum_{n\in G}f(n+1)\overline{f(n)}+
\sum_{n\in G}f(n-1)\overline{f(n)}\\
&=\sum_{n\in G}f(n+1)\overline{f(n)}+
\sum_{n\in G}f(n)\overline{f(n+1)}\\
\end{align}
which is real.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm missing something abundantly obvious, but how can we say that the final sum of summations is real?

Comment: I can see that if $f=a+0i$, then the complex conjugate would similarly be real and thus, the summations would be real.
However, if $f$ is of the form $a+bi$ for $b\neq 0$, then we would obtain something along the lines of 
$(a+bi)(c-di)+(a-bi)(c+di) \in \mathbb{R}$, but I feel like there may be a better/more clear way to see that the summations are obviously real.

Comment: @hungryformath It's equal to its conjugate.